# MaxIdleTime is not changeable for websocket connections in openfire

Tags: websocket, xmpp, openfire

I have installed websocket plugin of openfire. Now when on sparkweb side(client side) if a user's networks goes off then on openfire we can still see its presence for 5 minutes after which its presence is offline. When i saw the websocket plugin war file then it uses a xmppservlet which extends websocketServlet . In websocketServlet maxIdleTime is set which websocketServlet gets from int param but i dont see this init param's entry anywhere in any web.xml file

Below is the code snippet of websocketServlet where in init function maxidleTime is set:-
But i dont see the default 5 minutes entry of maxIdleTime in any web.xml

```
@Override
 public void init() throws ServletException
{
     try
     {
         String bs = getInitParameter("bufferSize");
         _webSocketFactory = new WebSocketFactory(this, bs == null ? 8192 : Integer.parseInt(bs));
         _webSocketFactory.start();

         String max = getInitParameter("maxIdleTime");
         if (max != null)
             _webSocketFactory.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(max));

         max = getInitParameter("maxTextMessageSize");
         if (max != null)
             _webSocketFactory.setMaxTextMessageSize(Integer.parseInt(max));

         max = getInitParameter("maxBinaryMessageSize");
         if (max != null)
             _webSocketFactory.setMaxBinaryMessageSize(Integer.parseInt(max));

         String min = getInitParameter("minVersion");
         if (min != null)
             _webSocketFactory.setMinVersion(Integer.parseInt(min));
     }
     catch (ServletException x)
     {
         throw x;
     }
     catch (Exception x)
     {
         throw new ServletException(x);
     }
 }
```

Does anybody has any idea how to set maxIdleTime ??

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the file(openfire-websockets/src/com/ifsoft/websockets/servlet/XMPPServlet.java)

```
@Override public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory)
{
    //set websocket idle timeout 30000
    factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(30000);
    factory.setCreator(new WSocketCreator());
}
```

It works for me. I also rebuild the plugin websockets.war at https://github.com/gunblues/strophe-openfire-websocket but only for openfire3.10